# Tabs cover up windows

Tags: bug, user-interface

Not sure how exactly to describe this, but tabs cover up windows. Take a look:

[image]

Found this when reviewing Reopen Votes on Meta.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a problem that affects all review pages. I have no idea why it hasn't been fixed yet. Solving it is a simple `z-index` change and there have been multiple updates to SE's CSS in the month+ that this has been a problem.

Comment: @Makyen It'll cost time and money to maintain the fix :P This is bad on worldbuilding.

Comment: If interested, I solved it by adding `.js-review-bar { z-index: 999; }` to the CSS I use for my personal adjustments. There's probably a number which is more "appropriate" within the `z-index` values which SE uses, but that worked for me.